# Elixir SFTP not working on server - key exchange failed

Tags: elixir

For some reason our server is unable to connect to an sftp server even though this code works when running locally. I can also connect with sftp on the command line from the server running our elixir app.

Elixir version: 1.10.4-otp-23

```
  connect("sftp.getevolved.com",
    user: "User",
    user_dir: "/etc/secrets/sftp",
    rsa_pass_phrase: ssh_passphrase()
  )

  def connect(host, opts) do
    opts =
      Keyword.merge(
        [
          user_interaction: false,
          silently_accept_hosts: true
        ],
        opts
      )
      |> Enum.map(fn
        {key, value} when is_binary(value) -> {key, value |> String.to_charlist()}
        value -> value
      end)

    with :ok <- @ssh.start,
         {:ok, channel_pid, connection} <-
           @ssh_sftp.start_channel(
             host |> String.to_charlist(),
             22,
             opts
           ) do
      {:ok, {channel_pid, connection}}
    end
  end
```

When I try to connect I get this error `{:error, 'Key exchange failed'}`. Which seems to imply that there is an algorithm issue. Is there a way to debug this more, I can't figure out how to get more info out of the connection about why it is failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out it was due to our app running in a k8s pod with a read only file system. I created a tmp writable directory and used that as `user_dir` and that fixed the issue.